# Scala + Play cannot compile in sbt

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I'm totally new in Play and Scala and I want to compile a rather old project and cannot understand how to make proper dependencies.

I have tried different scala versions, different play version, but didn't get any result

```
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.play:play-ahc-ws_2.11:2.8.20
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /Users/myuser/.ivy2/localcom.typesafe.play/play-ahc-ws_2.11/2.8.20/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-ahc-ws_2.11/2.8.20/play-ahc-ws_2.11-2.8.20.pom
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/com/typesafe/play/play-ahc-ws_2.11/2.8.20/play-ahc-ws_2.11-2.8.20.pom
[error]   not found: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-ahc-ws_2.11/2.8.20/play-ahc-ws_2.11-2.8.20.pom
[error]   forbidden: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com/typesafe/play/play-ahc-ws_2.11/2.8.20/play-ahc-ws_2.11-2.8.20.pom
[error]   not found: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/typesafe/play/play-ahc-ws_2.11/2.8.20/play-ahc-ws_2.11-2.8.20.pom
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-ahc-ws_2.11/2.8.20/play-ahc-ws_2.11-2.8.20.pom
```

Comment: I also have problems in downloading:
`Error downloading com.typesafe.play:twirl-api_2.11:1.5.1
Error downloading com.typesafe.play:play-server_2.11:2.8.20
Error downloading com.typesafe.play:filters-helpers_2.11:2.8.20
Error downloading com.typesafe.play:play-ebean_2.11:6.2.0
Error downloading com.typesafe.play:play-java-forms_2.11:2.8.20
Error downloading com.typesafe.play:play-akka-http-server_2.11:2.8.20
Error downloading com.typesafe.play:play-java-jdbc_2.11:2.8.20
Error downloading com.typesafe.play:play-logback_2.11:2.8.20`

Comment: Looks like you set scala 2.11 and Play 2.8.20 for the project. Try to set scala 2.13 at least. There are a seed template for play. If that doesn't work, try to edit your question sharing your build.sbt file

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, you are trying to use a Play version 2.8.20 that is not available for Scala 2.11.

This can be verified either in the official documentation or on the [central Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-ahc-ws) where the library (part of Play) you have an error with is only compiled for Scala 2.12 and 2.13.

If you are starting a new project, use Play 2.8.20 and Scala 2.13.12 (as of September 2023).

If you are trying to upgrade an old project, go step by step: probably start by going from Scala 2.11 to 2.12 and then 2.13, picking the latest available versions of libs for each Scala version.